# Simulate Stylus Input

Tags: linux, input, simulate, wacom

I am looking for a way to inject wacom input into a running X server. I kind of get stuck at the beginning finding any resources about this topic.

There is a lot of information about how to inject keystrokes and mouse input, but thats not what i am looking for and it does not seem to simlutate wacom stuff.

Does anyone have any informations about this topic?

Comment: A similar question on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239823/use-laptop-trackpad-as-graphics-tablet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On Linux, the various input devices generate a [variety of events](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt).

For example,

```
Keyboards - EV_KEY
Mice      - EV_REL
Tablets   - EV_ABS
```

The events supported/generated by any particular input device can be identified by running **`xinput`** on the system with the input device connected to it as follows:

```
xinput --list <name of the connected input device>
```

A sample list of input devices created by connecting a Wacom tablet:

```
$ > xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos4 6x9 eraser                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos4 6x9 cursor                  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos4 6x9 pad                     id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos4 6x9 stylus                  id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

..and the list of input events supported/generated by one of the 4 Wacom devices that are registered to input events from the Wacom tablet:

```
$ > xinput --list "Wacom Intuos4 6x9 eraser"
Wacom Intuos4 6x9 eraser                    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 8 classes:
        Class originated from: 17
        Buttons supported: 9
        Button labels: None None None None None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 17
        Keycodes supported: 248
        Class originated from: 17
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Abs X
          Range: 0.000000 - 44704.000000
          Resolution: 200000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 17
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Abs Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 27940.000000
          Resolution: 200000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 17
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Abs Pressure
          Range: 0.000000 - 2048.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 17
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Abs Tilt X
          Range: -64.000000 - 63.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 17
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: Abs Tilt Y
          Range: -64.000000 - 63.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 17
        Detail for Valuator 5:
          Label: Abs Tilt Y
          Range: -64.000000 - 63.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
```

> The above shows 9 buttons, and several axes with their corresponding min/max values for each type of input event(referred to by their lables).

For example, the absolute x axis has a min/max of 0 - 44704 units, with 20000 units/m. Presumably input events of type `EV_ABS` are generated only within this range for the X-axis.

> Once the types of events being generated by the input device have been identified, it is easy to inject fake events into the Xinput queue using `uinput` framework. A simple example is available **[here](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput)**

As you intend to simulate a Wacom tablet, you would probably need to inject all the input events that a typical Wacom tablet generates when used.

> `xinput` can be used to monitor the sequence and timing of input events generated by an actual device as shown in this **[answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129171/129246)**.